# Find all holomorphic functions with given real part

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all holomorphic functions $ f(z) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$ with $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ if :
$$  u(x,y) = \frac{x\cos{y} + y \sin{y}}{x^2+y^2} e^x $$

$$  u(x,y) = y\cos{x}\cosh{y} - (x+1) \sin{x} \sinh{y} $$

I don't think the right way to solve this is by writing $dv$ in terms of the partial derivatives of $u$ (because of C-R conditions) because things get complicated. I wonder if there is some other way of solving those.

The first answer should be (but I wonder if this is the right answer) :

$$ f(z) = \frac{1+i}{2} + c $$

And the second one :

$$ f(z) = (z+1) \cos{z} $$

Comment: See Schwarz integral formula https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_integral_formula